# Publishing reports to different folders for Sql Server Data Tools VS 2013

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

We have a project set up, but all of the reports are in the Reports folder.  On our SSRS we have many different folders.

Currently we make a new report and publish it then we have to manually move it into a folder.

How do we make a new report and designate we want this report to publish to a specific folder instead of the default root level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would restructure the solution. You can create a solution that has multiple SSRS projects and each project can have its own folder. Please see screen shots below.

[image]

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Looks like it is the only way.  Thank you.